# Splitting the color legend in a repeat spec in vega

Tags: bar-chart, vega-lite, vega

I am using a dataset with the following columns: date, counts, country, engine, and type.

I have created a view with three charts using the `repeat` operator. The charts show dates on the X axis, counts on Y, and then the bars are split by either country, engine, or type.

I am happy with how things look but I would like to have three separate color legends, one for each domain (so a legend for countries, a legend for type, and a legend for engine). How do I do that?

Here is the [link to the editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJgpgzgxgTgSwA4BcEHsB2IBcIB0hIANCAO4JgoAWuAHAAwOnUQIDm1KuAbE6UgCGYMAkztcAVlJwISCIO44A2iBQBPeSRAx0AV0wo467RHFiIIALqko8mLlABbQXADWjtZst4ARq5AAX1IzXVFxTwAPTwAzBAgAGzBccEVLUjQnCABVTAQlVJMM7xSUCCckdDhBBO00FASfVLKg0hMcUEF2dll2NJSoPSdtOMTkvF0DFCg6krwARz1BQ3zFBAA3dLV8xpTJwxngnXQEqtj4pM9ZeUUU64VuI40tPEx0JzEaoMCjsEVBTzrGp6aC4ZSgP4tPAAJgY0IAjABaBhIlHafbTXDQ0gY4wpTC1ELmTBNUTQRKzF4gXx6Q7ECH9GFw1Go6Ho-QHXg4jlGdogAmmYmk+JQCnFKk0ukMqEgWEI5GogDM7KmMxw0mOUzxr0JIDM7AsKTJot1zyakta0qacpZyIALCrOThFdytXyBUSDSSjSKxV4JbTLc1rcyFcjJI7MTh4a7DNr+br9Ya8Ma-WaUhbglaUjawwweJG1djNXH3YmhT7yaa5tTA1ngznQyiFYWsbHeRmtknvSnfdWA1KG0z5c24a31e3474uxXe1XKea6-Sh7Km0rxxrcXzp4KvcL5+LF4PISGR6iHe21TGSx2-DO95WTQuM0vs8PbQwI5fcNet53d8m4B9s+fiviuuajgW344MWf53gBPZAQe-pHkGJ6NmeLbQbBPLxh6eqzkhT6HqUcB6DAHj1uh755my0E8JOZYIfuxEoaR5GUcu1GrphDDKtBm64UxnqAam-ZNEYHFoYyPEfheN5qi6N54eWD5zqx6Z4JJFHSTKEGol+Ck-ox+KqaJwEkVpZE6VRMn6ciUFGTBJk6sxj5pjW2mcW+sl5vC444W6-4iYhYkgWo1neeBa7InRTmCUF8EhSxHlUl5umnh+-HxS51L3uZyGaRFUm2XpMUMPJGJXrlO7Je54nsTZXF2eVhlVcZynbvloUWWxVklc1ZW8Y57XOZ1wUEWpRGpRJkUZRhH7+dhuX4d2TR9DMlnFU1Pn2WO9ErWZiEbeF6WlZlebZaNCWlqZbl4CdW1nYNF2jpVPKKYd90gI9fXbVF3F7W1H0dXBCbfb9RXPbt5UjSDY1g6thGQ55c3nQtfkBTV3XrYIm1-dD0W8XF13YxDeOnWjL0Y6OV3wzdt55eT+NQ1TMO8e9qqg0JE1rSkKNpWzRMfsDXPRmTdUPRTT1C4DsNY+NSWTYBAuzQN7NyeOv480rfPqTNpGCDAKBnOjNGjqLTra4lTOS9NDVWUbJtwPN5uonDYuBbduuEWFMtO6b1Nu1hTle4zSNTarhvG4HGu0eODGK+DdtR47Mcu2bvm0xuX0p9LBPVOnrtZ+e45KYjR24yzqMBxnQcl+GWu58rx356ztfF3tHtOmHKnM5THeZ3tS2hxLLdVwPRdD+VJP02Pes-W3NdT-Xe102LDNTjj-NL4Lg+r+VnNW-PyO77N+9xxbTdJ7V4879Xe8r5f7sK2Dt8L6nEWD1YPxAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have independent color scales & legends, add the following at the top level of the chart specification:

```json
"resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent"}}
```

For more information, see https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/resolve.html.

Comment: Thanks. As an occasional, after-hours user I am again impressed by how flexible the spec is.

Comment: Btw, what is the best way to set legend titles when using the repeat spec? I have tried adding `legend.title` inside `spec.mark.enconding.color` but that (obviously) sets the same title for all three charts. Hoped a three element array could do the trick `("title" : ["Vehicle type", "Country of origin", "Fuel"]}` but no..